# Запустить Skype из приложения Android

Tags: java, android, skype

В общем хочу сделать возможность набора через `Skype`. В случае когда у меня есть `<user_name>` - я делаю так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + skypeUserName));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

после чего, если имя пользователя правильное - то запускается `Skype` и начинается звонок. В случае если `<user_name>` неправильный или его просто нету я хочу просто запускать `Skype` , экран с контактами, например! Как такое можно реализовать, просто запускать приложение в таком виде в каком оно бы запустилось если бы я нажал  на иконку приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `skypeUserName` неизвестен, то запускать Skype можно так:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider")
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Отлично, запускает как надо.